# How can I represent data in a WYSIWYG format without using Crystal Reports?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, printing, dataset, reporting

I am searching a way to print data in tablesw with text and images, in a WYSIWYG, nice and good looking way.

So far I have: header + images + web-like decorations + arabic labels & values + data in dataset (xml)
+ I need to give a way for buisness analysts to change the output layout.

**Crystal Report does all of this.
But I don't like Crystal Reports.**

**Is there a good print technology?**

Does anyone have any ideas for something to do: Dataset->xml->html with xslt?

Comment: Mind sharing how crystal reports do this with images?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your database you are using, but there is always SQL Server Reporting Services. I tend to like it a lot more than Crystal Reports.

Edit: I would like to add that Reporting Services does in fact have a full GUI for development (Visual Studio), and it allows for exporting of reports into many different formats such as Word, Excel, PDF, HTML, etc.

Comment: thanks. This is not exactly reporting : the dataset info is only local (in a .NET winform application). I use crystal just to print all infos.

Comment: It is still reporting you're printing data from a dataset.

Comment: Crystal Reports is a reporting tool.