# Show formatted WYSIWYG field in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

I am working on an application where it is necessary that the text that a user enters be formatted, be it bold, italic, point forms etc. For this reason I have elected to use a https://summernote.org/

Everything is fine and gets saved to my database. The problem is, when pulling up a crystal reports I am unsure how to do that without pulling in the tags and basically raw information that is in the database.

I've seen various links such as this on [How can I represent data in a WYSIWYG format without using Crystal Reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585929/how-can-i-represent-data-in-a-wysiwyg-format-without-using-crystal-reports)
That seems to suggest it can be done however I am not seeing where or what im supposed to change to get it ton work correctly.

Would be greatful if someone could point it out for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the field, Format Field... 
Select Paragraph tab
Set Text Interpretation to 'HTML Text'.

This would handle basic HTML formatting. For more advanced HTML scenarios, there's a solution via a UFL (user function library).

Comment: HTML Text works, but as you mentioned the image doesnt, appreciate it if you could direct to this solution library, havent been able to find it with my searches just yet.